# Print a clean table (with not too much else) from raw SQL or ActiveRecord query in rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Is there a way to output results of executing raw SQL in the rails console more cleanly?

#### Example

Is there a way to get raw sql output a little cleaner in the rails console?

For example, this query `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query("SELECT * from categories_pages;")`

gives:

```
  SQL (0.5ms)  SELECT * from categories_pages;
=> #<ActiveRecord::Result:0x000000011341db60
 @column_types=
  {"category_id"=>
    #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQL::OID::Uuid:0x0000000110bb2950
     @limit=nil,
     @precision=nil,
     @scale=nil>,
   "page_id"=>
    #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQL::OID::Uuid:0x0000000110bb2950
     @limit=nil,
     @precision=nil,
     @scale=nil>},
 @columns=["category_id", "page_id"],
 @hash_rows=nil,
 @rows=[["4068bbb0-2450-45c0-91c7-392f6cb55129", "b31bc725-c2f3-4b29-affb-cc0899a90354"]]>
```

but  I was hoping for is something much cleaner (this is the same data, just much more cleanly presented):

```
category_id                                  page_id
"4068bbb0-2450-45c0-91c7-392f6cb55129"       "b31bc725-c2f3-4b29-affb-cc0899a90354"
```

Comment: I had the question and found one answer, which I will put below. I post the question/answer in case it can help any one else. I will not accept my own answer in case there are better ways.

Comment: I just run `rails db` in another window and copy/paste the SQL into psql.  Its not as fancy but it doesn't rely on a gem thats not currently maintained.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `table_print` gem, which is a simple gem you install and can then use in the rails console to print a clean table of results (and nothing else) like so.

Install gem:

```
gem install table_print
```

In rails console:

```
tp Physician.all
```

Note: the method works with `ActiveRecord::Result` (i.e. from executing raw SQL as in the question) but also with the more common `Page::ActiveRecord_Relation` class.

Note: there is a 3 minute video explaining the gem [here](http://tableprintgem.com/).